# Unable to click on buttons/Links on Safari browser using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, safari

Unable to click on buttons/Links on Safari browser.

It does not throw any exception moves to the next line of code but actual click operation is not performed on the page.

Using selenium version - 2.52

Comment: Please add code/configuration details

Comment: Do read [how to ask questiong](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on this forum. Always try to give a clear picture of what you are trying to do, where it is failing. Paste your code and error stacktrace that you are getting. Btw...welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and got it resolved by adding piece of code instead of selenium click

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", [YOUR LOCATOR]);
```